# Prompt that asks for the SSH credentials is broken (Eclipse on Mac OS X)

Tags: eclipse, macos, ssh

I'm using a ssh-key to login to my Bitbucket account, but when I try connect my Eclipse to that there's a prompt asking for the passphrase showing like the following:

[image: Enter passphrase for key '/Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa']

Notice that the field to enter the passphrase is not appearing, despite the fact that the prompt is asking for it.

I remember some time ago trying to fix an issue with XQuartz related to ssh (it may be related), but it was a long time ago, so I don't remember what I did at the time.

Comment: Eclipse is probably broken. You would have to use non-encrypted private key or ssh-agent running.

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje, I guess I'll try to update my Eclipse and then I'll share the result.

Comment: Nope, updated the Eclipse to Neon.2, but the issue is still the same...

Comment: By running `ssh-add` before opening Eclipse hides the problem, but it comes back whenever the ssh-agent is not running.

Answer (score 0):

This is (most probably) a bug in Eclipse or some of its plugins providing this dialog. I think it only expects that there will be prompt for yes/no, which is used to verify server host keys. You should consider filling a bug.

As a workaround, you can remove the passphrase from the key (well ... not recommended, because it makes it much less secure) or run `ssh-agent` and add the keys to it before starting eclipse.